# What port should use HTTP transport based WCF service?

Tags: wcf

What port should use WCF HTTP transport based service? I created WCF service and Visual Studio assigned address http://localhost:7517/
But some customers can use web proxies and it seems that using standard 80 or 8080 is good idea, isn't it? How to force WCF client to use proxy to get to WCF service? From other side we should be confident that port 80 is not occupied by some web server. Is it correct to require from customer isolating WCF service on separate server to avoid collision? What is the best practice?
**UPDATED:** 80 port is bad candidate: system (Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 for example) uses it often: [Why is System process listening on Port 80?](https://superuser.com/questions/43307/why-is-system-process-listening-on-port-80)

Comment: Are you intending to host in IIS?  If so it is perfectly fine to use port 80.  It is also perfectly fine if you _don't intend to use IIS_ in your deployment and you know IIS (or other web servers) won't be present. Why? Because port 80 is generally left open by IT when configuring firewalls and so your clients are more likely to reach your service over the Internet.  That's why you'll see many non-HTTP (including SQL server including in your link) servers using port 80 because they know it's generally a sure thing.

Comment: Thank you - these is the reasons I'm thinking about. Unfortunately we don't know network topology of customer. All that I know is that it is intranet with some collaboration zones in other countries and some locations use http proxy (port of proxy 80). Is it common for proxy to connect to ANY destination port indicated in HTTP request? Or usually set of destination ports is restricted (80, 8080, 443, ...)

Comment: I guess they could lock it down to certain destinations.  This is the limit of my knowledge sadly

Comment: Specialization rules! We can track here: http://serverfault.com/questions/767161/is-it-common-for-http-proxy-to-connect-to-any-destination-port-indicated-in-http

Comment: Oh nice one.  Hope you get it going. :)